# How to stop playing loaded video and load a new one when url changes using React Player?

Tags: reactjs, react-player

I added the `React Player` into my application and it look like:

```
 {videos ? <ReactPlayer url={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videos.id.videoId}`} />
         :
  <h1>No video</h1>}
```

It works fine, but when i change url nothing happens, i would like to know how can i stop current video and load a new one whe, url changes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might some logic which prevent the actual video tag in `ReactPlayer` re-render when you change url, Theoretically, A component will be completely re-rendered when you set a key an change that key.

Let try this:

```
<ReactPlayer key={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videos.id.videoId}` url={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videos.id.videoId}`} />
```

Comment: I believe it works, but not in my case, I think I do something wrong, could you please extend your answer this full example ? I added render method where placed <React player.../> Component and added button which calls this method, but nothing happens :(

Comment: I create a codesanbox which don't event need `key` still can change video:https://codesandbox.io/s/great-agnesi-iqir9?file=/src/App.js

I think something working with your render, could you all full code of your component?